# css drawn 6-points star place inside the Button link

Tags: css

I found a code drawing a 6-point star:

```
#star-six {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid red;
position: relative;
}
#star-six:after {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 100px solid red;
position: absolute;
content: "";
top: 30px;
left: -50px;
}
```

now I need to place this picture inside the Button element.
 should look like a real button with 6-point start on the left side.

|*Button| Like this :)

Comment: post your code with Demo. so we have an idea what you are doing.

Comment: im not sure exactly what the css you posted does, but it sure doesnt draw anything because you dont draw with css at all. please also post your html so we can see whats going on

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star/

Comment: @Banana of course it can't draw, but the browser will render the element (wiht id star-six) looking like a 6-point star, just a css trick called CSS triangle.

Comment: i see, cool effect :)

Comment: Your problem is the star element must have `relative` position, so to center it vertically is a challenge unless you use some transform or fixed positioning (with a little pre-calculation for the offset and adjustion first), try this example fiddle as a sample to research more http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2nh/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try including a div inside of a  tag - something like this code here: 
`<button onclick="sayHello();"><div id="star-six">&nbsp;</div></button>`
http://jsfiddle.net/53mHn/

Updated: 
If you want the star on the left, create two divs inside of your button, one for the star and one for your text. Set the width of the star div to be 50px (or whatever the star width is) and set the float: to left.

```
<button onclick="sayHello();"><div class="star-content star-icon" id="star-six">&nbsp;</div><div class="star-content">This is the text inside of my button</div></button>
```

Css is here:

```
.star-icon {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: he asked for the star to be on the left side.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/53mHn/1/
The trick is to create a div for the star, and then a div for your text inside the button, then set the div for the star to float: left.